# What is this detector?

Tags: sensor

I want to improve my rowing machine by making it connected with a RPI. 
I know it counts every pass with this little guy:
[image: The sensor]
But I’m wondering how it works (and why it has two pluses). 
I’m pretty sure it’s a magnetic sensor but that’s all I know!

Comment: Can you open it? It's a relay? Maybe?

Comment: it's probably a reed switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's it's non contact and magnetic then it's very likely it's a reed switch.They work by shorting the contacts when the magnet is near.

For use by a microcontroller you can wire them up exactly like a pushbutton.

They don't support high currents so if you want to use them as direct switches you will need some kind of buffer.